# Is there a styles API for Android Wear 2.0?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm checking out the new Android Wear 2.0 developer preview. Now I know that the complication API is going to be public, but one thing I've noticed is that on the Google default watchface: Elements Analog, there is also a styles menu under settings that lets you change the watchface colors.

Does anyone know if this is going to be (or maybe already is) a part of the public Android Wear API?

Comment: Try reading about the [Providing Configuration Activities](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/configuration.html) in 
Creating Watch Faces document.  As far as I know, you will be setting up configuration parameters to let users customize how the watch face looks and behaves. It can be done using the Companion or the Wearable(less complicated because complex menus are hard to navigate on smaller screens. Also check their [sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/index.html) demonstrates handheld and wearable configuration activities. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API to set the style color for watch face, you should create one by yourself in the watch face setting.

You can read [Providing Configuration Activities](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/configuration.html) to provide a setting activity for watch face.